# HDMI Input onto a MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv, airplay, hdmi

I have a Canon DSLR camera and I am trying to get the output from the camera onto a MacBook Air so I can then AirPlay the MacBook to a different Room.  The other room is on the other side of a school campus so running a cable would not work.

The Canon has an HDMI output and if it is plugged into a TV or monitor it will display fine, as expected.  However I am trying to get the feed from the camera onto a MacBook Air.  I know desktop computers back in the day had TV tuner cards for a similar function, but I am not sure about the MacBooks.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Air and similar MacBooks do not provide HDMI inputs, only outputs. Although there is a device that will allow you input HDMI if you are willing to pay for it. (Usually fairly expensive) Something like this is what you are looking for: www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hdpvr.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a game capture device for this. Elgato HD is one, but I don't recommend it as it doesn't play well with Mac.